# Problem regarding my Discord Bot | Cannot Read hasPermission of null | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

My bot crashes pretty often, and I am unable to locate the issue. I have tried several things but all of them have not caused the error. The Bot is supposed to delete Messages that contain Cusswords in German.

```js
client.on ('message', message => {
    if (message.author.id === "715567779624779787") {}
    else if (message.content === "!help" || message.content === "!link") {}
    else if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
        message.reply("Ich filtere nur auf Servern. Versuche !help oder !link.");
    } else if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {} 
    else if (config.filter_list.some(word => message.content.toUpperCase().includes(word))) {
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

The ID, is the Bots ID. The Error showing UP is this guy here:

```js
 } else if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\bot.js:27:38)
    at Client.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
```

I am unable to locate the Issue for the Error message. Please Ignore my Long File Paths :D

Thank you in Advance,

Luis

Comment: `message.member` is not valid. Did you meant to write `message.author`?

Comment: Never knew that message.member is invalid. Will try it tho. Thanks

Comment: // Update: message.author.hasPermission throws an Error:

          } else if (message.author.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
                                     ^

TypeError: message.author.hasPermission is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Scheiße die sich verpissen soll\LuisChat\bot.js:27:38)

Comment: This is what the documentation says: member: Represents the author of the message as a guild member. Only available if the message comes from a guild where the author is still a member. Could it be that the author left the guild?

Comment: Well the Bot checks the message the second it was sent. If the message was sent per DM, he will not react. So the user could leave the guild - but as the bot only checks for the time he is on the guild that is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help, all. I figured the Problem was caused through Discord System Notifications, which aren't detected as a Bot nor as a member with a certain Permission.
I have fixed it by using `if (message.author.client || message.author.bot) {} else return;`. This simply checks if the author is either a client or a bot.

-Luis

Answer (score 0):

```
message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")
```

**change it to **

```
message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")
```